# Select one string line in a list

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox

I'm trying to simply select one string line out a long list strings that are held on a server and seperated with a pipe character. This string is grabbed by a php script and the string line is a list of all the media and folders I have on my server.

In my code I'm getting this information and returning it with the following code:

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
 {
     result = client.DownloadString("http://server.foo.com/images/getDirectoryList.php");
 }

  textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Split('|'));
```

And it looks like this:

But when I try to simply click on one of them, my cursor simply just goes to where I've clicked. Like this, I tried to select md-harrier.jpg and my cursor just ends up at the end of jpg:

What I'm really wanting is pictured below. I click on Koala.jpg and the whole thing is highlighted and I have the ability to store the name of what it is I've just clicked on. TO achieve that screen shot I had to click next to Koala.jpg and then drag my mouse along.

Is there anyway I can achieve what I want to achieve?

The key thing to note about this is that I will have no idea how many files will be on the server, nor what they will be called. My php script is grabbing this information and displaying it in my winform text box using the code I have wrote above.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use a text box instead of a list box?

Comment: No reason at all. If that can allow me to do what I want, I'm happy to switch. Never used a list box before.

Comment: Have a look at the [`ListBox` entry on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx). There are a few example scattered here and there. What you want is to assign the `DataSource` to your splitted list and listen to the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` / `OnSelectedValueChanged` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Simon said you need a `ListBox`, a `ListBox` fits here because it allows you to select a line, and you can register to the event of `SelectedIndexChanged` and store the name that was selected.

to initiate the values do

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
 {
     result = client.DownloadString("http://bender.holovis.com/images/getDirectoryList.php");
 }

listBox1.Items.AddRange(result.Split('|'));
listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

and on the selectedItemChanged:

```
  string currVal;

  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     currVal = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have no reason to use TextBox,then by using ListBox you can achieve that in this way;

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
 result = client.DownloadString("http://bender.holovis.com/images/getDirectoryList.php");
}
string[] names=result.Split('|');
foreach(string name in names)
{
if(name!="|"&&name!=" ")
{
  listbox.Items.Add(name);
}
}
```

Additionally,if you would like to store selected item in a variable subscribe to `ListBox's SelectionChangedEvent` and store the selection index in a variable in this way;

```
int selection=;

private void ListBox1_SelectionIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  selection=ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```